# Literature on Binary regression trees

Tags: regression, machine-learning, references, cart

I'm interested in learning how to use binary regression trees. Therefore I would like to know if there are any seminal papers in the development/application of binary regression trees? As well as if there are any potentially booklength sources on the topic of regression trees?

I am using the R-package *rpart* which cites the works

L. Breiman, J.H. Friedman, R.A. Olshen, , and C.J Stone. *Classification and RegressionTrees.*  Wadsworth, Belmont, Ca, 1983.

L.A. Clark and D. Pregibon.  *Tree-based models.*  In J.M. Chambers and T.J. Hastie,editors,Statistical Models in S, chapter 9. Wadsworth and Brooks/Cole, Pacific Grove,Ca, 1992.

But since these are of an older date I suspect newer material to be available. Also I am familiar with *Elements of Statistical Learning*.

Comment: Some good references are cited in this [Previous Question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/257537/141956)

Comment: thx yes that is very interesting :)